# Let $A$ be an abelian group. Show that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z_n, \mathbb Z) = 0$, for any $n \ge 2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is:

Let $A$ be an abelian group. Show that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z_n, \mathbb Z) = 0$, for any $n \ge 2$.

So I know from a previous proof that $A$ is an abelian group and $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z, A)$ is isomorphic to $A$.

In the new proof, I am to show a contradiction but I am having trouble getting my proof started.

Comment: Hint: The image of an element of finite order has finite order.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for pointing out my mistake. You are totally right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\in \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z_n, \mathbb Z)$ and let $f(\overline 1)=s$ so $f(\overline n)=f(\overline0)=ns=0$ so $s=0$ and then $f=0$.

Comment: Stepping into group theory, too! +1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: as every element in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can be written as a finite sum of $1$s, any homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is fully determined by the image of $1$. Now, suppose $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_n\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism and $f(1)=k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then what is $f(\underbrace{1+\ldots +1}_m)$? What happens if $m=n$?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $\operatorname{Hom}(G, \Bbb Z) = 0$ for any finite group $G$. To see why, let $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(G, \Bbb Z)$. Since $G$ is finite, $f(G)$ must be finite. It is an elementary result that any subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ has the form $m\Bbb Z$ for some integer $m$; this follows from the Euclidean algorithm. Since $0$ is the only finite subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, it follows that $f(G) = 0$. Hence $f = 0$.